# How to include a variable in a json file for an environment variable?

Tags: json, redis

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
"redisClient": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

However I have recently updated my redis-server to require a password, so I need to include the password before the host. I have an environment variable which is in my .env file which looks like this

```
REDIS_ACCESS_KEY =   SDGJKSDGSJG4124124
```

I would like to be able to do something along these lines:

```
"redisClient": "redis://:process.env.REDIS_ACCESS_KEY@127.0.0.1:6379"
```

But this is not working. How can I include my ACESS_KEY variable so that the end goal is that redisClient =  `"redis://SDGJKSDGSJG4124124127.0.0.1:6379"`?

Comment: You might want to mention your environmental information. OS, development stack, etc.

Comment: Using a linux VM @EugeneS.

Comment: you can put it in the same connection string like `redis://:mypass@addr:port/db-number`? why separated it ?